# How to print matched pattern followed by parentheses containing some values?

Tags: unix, grep

I am currently stuck with a scenario where i need to print the matched pattern which is followed by parentheses containing different values. For eg:

```
echo "abc(123) += abc(245678) ^%$&** abc(3)" | grep -o 'abc(.*)'
```

gives the entire line.

I want the o/p to be only :

```
abc(123) 
abc(245678) 
abc(3)
```

I know in `grep -o 'abc(.*)'`, the closing bracket is being taken as the last bracket in the line and hence printing the entire line.

I was trying to figure out some way to find the location of the closing bracket of the respective open bracket, but not able to find out. Kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `[^)]` (negation) matching. Like this.

```
echo "abc(123) += abc(245678) ^%$&** abc(3)" | grep -o 'abc([^)]*)'
```

If the first character of the list is the caret `^` then it matches any character not in the list.

Comment: @amitkumar, Glad it worked for you. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted if your problem is already solved. You can do it clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green. See [HelpCenter](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you have any questions.